# Unable to send text messages on some Android Phones using SmsManager

Tags: android, sms

My mobile app occasionally is sending text messages, everything works great on most phones but i am starting to receive emails from some users stating the messages aren't going out. Here is the code i am using:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("+12223334444", null, "test sms", null, null);
```

I've read somewhere that I should use the PendingIntent, so i tried it as follows:

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);                     
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

So far I have gotten emails from users of Samsung Galaxy S II, Sprint Evo Shift, Samsung Sidekick phones.

**Please keep in mind it's not phone specific, i have tested the app on two of these phones (my friends) and the text message was sent normally**

Comment: could you provide full package name of SmsManager?

Comment: @Selvin - it's from "android.telephony.SmsManager"

Comment: Have you put permission in the manifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

Comment: @manojchauhan - of course. like i said, it works on almost all phones but not on the Galaxy SII

Comment: i'm sure that he did since as he wrote that it's working on other devices ... anyway i've just tested on SGS II (with standard 2.3.6 EU ROM) and it's working ...

Comment: thanks @Selvin, have you tried sending the SMS to self? also i am standardizing the phone number into "+[countrycode][phonenumber]" when i send messages, does that have to do anything?

Comment: yes, i've send sms to myself using +coutry[num]

Comment: @selvin - ok, well that doesn't help :) any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: it's hard to "debug" application on customer device ... try to use acra(google+acra) and do some logs from this devices ... without this it'll be just guessing

Comment: Ok, i updated the question since i found out this is not GalaxyS2 specific bug, it's happening on other phones as well so it's phone specific. Why wouldn't SmsManager work in certain cases?

Comment: do you users have an SMS plan ?

Comment: Have you find out the solution ?  I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you aren't handling retries at all. It is possible for the SMS to fail to send in a variety of colourful ways. You can listen for these events using the sent `PendingIntent` using something like:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (getResultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // failed to send the sms, see SmsManager.ERROR_<description> for more info on why
    }
}
```

What I suspect is happening is that users have no signal at the time you send the message, so it fails and never retries. This would also explain why it isn't device specific.