# SMS Based Validation for Android - Closing the SMS window after sending

Tags: android, sms

I'm looking for some quick feedback on developing an in-app SMS validation solution as part of my registration process for an Android app.  The guy on my team working on the issue seems to be having trouble.

Disclaimer: I am not a developer myself, just have basic coding knowledge.

Basically what *should* happen is this:

1. User enters phone number
2. User selects a "validate number by SMS" button
3. SMS compose window is launched.  Message field is pre-populated with
   a validation code.  Recipient number pre-populated with a Twilio
   phone number connected to my server
4. Once the user hits send, the SMS window should automatically close
   once the message is successfully sent, returning them to my app's
   registration process where it will be either waiting to receive a
   response from the server or checking at intervals to see if it has
   permission (i.e. the phone number was verified) to move to the next
   phase of registration.

The problem is with step #4, as my developer has indicated that he doesn't have an object tied to the messaging app, so he is unable to call functions on it... This is where my coding knowledge falls short, so I'd like to hear how others have (or would have) solved this problem.  I'm *sure* that it is solvable.

Thanks!

Comment: I spent a considerable amount of time trying to accomplish this and was successful only at *either* getting the SMS composer pre-populated with data *or* getting it to return to my app after sending. Setting it up to return to my app would invariably prevent the composer from pre-populating. I wish you luck in solving this and will be watching for a miracle, but I'm pretty sure I've already exhausted all of the available options to no avail.

Comment: Here's the bug for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58153 Interestingly, they state that this is only occurring since Jelly Bean 4.3. If that's really the case then you might be able to conditionally run this the way you (and I) want if the user is on a previous version then only send it in-app on 4.3 devices.

Comment: My developer actually just came up with a solution that appears to work.  As we aren't technically able to control another app (in this case the sms composer), what we did was just cause our app to re-open on top of the sms composer after the message is sent.  I'd be curious if anyone thinks this will cause any undesirable behavior or problems because it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: How are you detecting that the message was sent so your app knows to re-open?

Answer (score 1):

dont use the text message app intent and just send it within your app

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ccc, 0, new Intent(), 0);
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
```

Comment: I believe we originally went this route, but were having trouble with a considerable number of devices.  Here's a thread that describes the same issue that we were experiencing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852625/unable-to-send-text-messages-on-some-android-phones-using-smsmanager.  It appears no one has offered any ideas on possible reasons this would be happening, and as it was part of my registration process, I didn't want to risk losing users.

Comment: This is what I resorted to in my app, but there's the huge caveat that the permission for sending SMS is looked at very suspiciously by users, especially because on newer devices it's accompanied by a conspicuous golden coin icon and the annotation that "This may cost you money."

Comment: well this is the only option you have really since you cannot control the Messaging app. The only way to get back to your app is the user has to manually hit the back button from there

Comment: That's not strictly true. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375561/return-to-activity-after-action-completed-in-android The problem is that if you *also* attempt to pre-populate the SMS fields those intent extras are not properly observed. The SMS appears blank. (Though if you hit send, it does send the message you specified, but no user is going to realize that.)

Comment: @goto10 that's exactly what we experienced when trying to solve the problem.  It's very odd how it doesn't display the information in the SMS fields, even though the information is really there.

Comment: so like I said you wont be able to do what you want, you will then either have to create your own messaging service or just let the user hit the back button to get back to your app like they are suppose to

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue. You should be able to do what you want with code like this (copied from link below):

```
private void launchSMSActivity(final CharSequence phoneNumber) {
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.setData(Uri.fromParts("sms", phoneNumber.toString(), null));
    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", mMessageWithPattern);
    smsIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
    smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(smsIntent, SEND_SMS);
}
```

However, there is apparently a bug in 4.3 that causes the message field to appear blank. Hitting send will still send the message. The bug is here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58153

Given that, your may choose to send from within the app per tyczj's answer, though keep in mind that doing so will require adding an SMS permission to your app. When users get the permission confirmation dialog it will appear at the top with a notice that it may cost them money. A number of malicious apps have used this permission to run up users' phone bills so many users look at it with suspicion.

You may also choose to only send SMS from within the app on 4.3 devices and use the code above to do it the way you want on all other devices. That doesn't solve the permission problem, unless you publish two APKs - one for pre 4.3 devices without the permission, and one for 4.3 with the permission. This last option is what I'm now considering for my own app.