# send and receive sms to verify mobile number

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do mobile number verification without using third party. For this my logic is this:-

- User enter their mobile number with country code
- When they click on verify button a intent will send a sms to user-defined mobile number with random unique id
- after that app broadcast will wait for 2 minute and when it receive sms then user can login or sign-up

Is this logic right or it need some modification?

To send sms i am using this code, but dont know how i  can recieve and validate number.

```
 String phoneNumber = "9999999999";
 String smsBody = "Message from the API";

 // Get the default instance of SmsManager
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
 // Send a text based SMS
 smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody, null, null);
```

**UPDATE:-**

Not receiving message on samsung device.

[this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224640/this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First I generate a random number within range 10000 to 99999.

```
 Random rNo = new Random();
 final int code = rNo.nextInt((99999 - 10000) + 1) + 10000;
```

Next I display a popup mentioning the user that a message will be sent from the mobile to verify the number. This is done using `AlertDialog`.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Verify Phone Number");
builder.setMessage("An sms will be sent to the number " + phNo + " for verification. Charges will apply as per your plan");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //code to send sms here with the code value
                final ProgressDialog progressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Waiting for SMS", "Please hold on");

                final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    Log.v("ranjapp", "Ticking " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                     progressdialog.setMessage("Waiting for the message " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                     getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                     progressdialog.dismiss();

                    }
                }.start();

                receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                        if (bundle != null) {
                            if (readSMS(intent, code)) {
                                Log.v("ranjapp", "SMS read");
                                timer.cancel();
                                try {
                                    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
     getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
            }
        }

);
builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

);
builder.show();
```

**Explanation of above code:**

After user acknowledges to send sms an sms is sent with the code to the entered number and this number should be the one that user is using himself. So we will wait for an sms with the code, to receive the sms and read its content we will create a `BroadCastReceiver` to listen to incoming sms.

Now also we need to start a timer so that we wait for only 2 minutes for the sms, so we start a `CountDownTimer` for 2 minutes at the end of 2 minutes the countdowntimer will unregister the receiver. The receiver is unregistered even if the code is received in the incoming sms so that we can free the resources.

Code to readSMS, if the code is found true is returned else false is returned,

```
boolean readSMS(Intent intent, int code) {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    if (message.contains(String.valueOf(code)))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ranjapp", "Exception here " + e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

To send SMS use below method:

```
public static void sendSMS(Context context, String incomingNumber, String sms) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM:SS");
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();                                      //send sms
        try {
            ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(sms);
            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(incomingNumber, null, parts, null, null);

            RecContDBHelper recContDBHelper = new RecContDBHelper(context);
            recContDBHelper.insertRecord(new ContactData("", incomingNumber, dtfOut.print(MutableDateTime.now())));
            Log.v("ranjith", "Sms to be sent is " + sms);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ranjith", e + "");
        }
    }
```

In AndroidManifest.xml you need to have these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: What is pdus is here?

Comment: A PDU is a “protocol data unit”, which is the industry format for an SMS message. Its a standard string to retrieve sms

Comment: Thanks. Nice Info. Can you please tell me how i can test this in emulator  with country code. For example my emulator number is 5554, And i am entering +91 as country code, SO complete number to send message is +915554, but i am not getting message.

Comment: In emulator it does not matter what number you use, all sms will be received by the emulated phone...Just enter any number but the generated code should be in the sms...Just print the randomly generated number in the log and copy the same and send the same code within sms...

Comment: getting this in emulator:     1234-1359/? E/MmsServiceBroker﹕ Can not connect to MmsService (timed out)
07-04 13:07:44.329    1234-1359/? E/JavaBinder﹕ *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out in connecting to MmsService

Comment: You have to send message from `android device monitor`..this link has tutorial of how to send sms from emulator  http://javapapers.com/android/android-receive-sms-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you.  I am getting this in log s   Log.v("ranjapp", "SMS read"); But waiting for message popup is not hiding. may be this is not working  Login.this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);

Comment: K..that means your sms is read and code was detected...If my answer helped you mark it answered..

Comment: You need to add this line of code after unregister    progressdialog.dismiss();

Comment: Marked and voted up. Thanks.  in emulator we are sending message by device monitor, So how can we check our message sending code is  working or not?

Comment: You can just print the message in onReceive method..or also you can read the message in the inbox of the emulator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82356/discussion-between-neo-and-htiuar).

Comment: Just try it in physical device once as this should finally end up in physical device

Comment: I tried, But on my device i am not able to send messages. I have samsung note 2. Also messages not showing in inbox.

Comment: I have just added code to sendsms and persmissions required in Androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Thanks. both code to send a sms is working on emulator, but not on my device. May be there is some problem in my device.

Comment: Facing this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852625/unable-to-send-text-messages-on-some-android-phones-using-smsmanager

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224640/this-requires-android-permission-interact-across-users-full

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Content Provider to access the sms inbox!

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver =getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    //query here
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this possible to access incoming message, not inbox?