# this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Tags: android, smsmanager

This problem related to this question

[send and receive sms to verify mobile number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190446/send-and-receive-sms-to-verify-mobile-number/31190937)

I have unlocked samsung at&t device. I am trying to send message by code. But my code is not working so i connected my device with USB and track whats the problem is. I found that i am getting this exception

```
981/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13175)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2044)
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:615)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-05 00:53:08.676    2411-2981/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
07-05 00:53:08.691  22617-22617/com.keepAeye.gps E/code is﹕ 29514
```

I added these permission in my manifest file

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

But still not working.

What should i do now?

I know there is several posts on this site about this issue but none of them helping me.

**UPDATE**

Here is my code to send message

```
  private void sendSMS1(String  phoneNumber, String  message)
{
    String  SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String  DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    sms.sendTextMessage("9501921***", null, "hello", sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

It's always going to generic failure. Don't know why.

Comment: try `clean & rebuild` once.

Comment: I did, But not working. strange thing is i am getting this in log 07-05 01:45:19.151  15785-15785/com.keepAeye.gps V/ranjith﹕ Sms to be sent is 68172
But still not receiving message in inbox.

Comment: Just post the code you are using to send sms and also how are you invoking it..

Comment: Please also check this http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=254902

Answer (score 1):

To be able to hold `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS`, your app has to be signed by the firmware's signing key or it has to be installed on the system partition.

To be able to hold `INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL`, your app has to be signed by the firmware's signing key.

Ordinary applications are not signed by the firmware's signing key, as that is for device manufacturers and those writing custom ROMs. Ordinary applications are not installed on the system partition, as that is for device manufacturers, those writing custom ROMs, and those who root their devices.

It is unclear why you think that the messages you show in your question pertain to your app. If you are sure that they do, you will need to determine what it is about your code that is triggering those messages, and then fix that code.

Comment: I am using this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190446/send-and-receive-sms-to-verify-mobile-number/31190937    . I didnt understand to send message via code why it needs INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS type permissions.

Comment: @neo: "why it needs INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" -- sending an SMS does not need that permission.